# Wordpress Hover dropdown menu

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

Hello I am new to wordpress and I want to create a simple dropdown menu. I know wordpress already has an option to create a submenu but it toggles on click not hover. This is what I want todo.. If you hover over over one of the items in the main nav, it will dropdown a submenu. If you click on an item in the main nav then it will take you and if you click on the submenu item then it will take you there as well. So basically I want it to toggle on hover rather than click. I know I could do this with css, but having trouble. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is done using the two CSS and javascript

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  padding: 15px auto 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 0;
}

<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item One</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem Three</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephcode/0b14ya3j/1/)